# Foundation Framework and React - reInit accordion not working

Tags: reactjs, zurb-foundation

## Problem

- I call setState to add a new recipe to my recipe list
- The recipe is a new panel in a Foundation accordion
- The accordion title pops up immediately
- There is no functionality until page refresh
- I have tried everything i can think of including Foundation's reInit, their manual toggle, up, and down methods for accordions, and re constructing the whole accordion
- nothing works

Comment: https://codepen.io/benjaminadk/pen/vZrXgV

Answer (score 0):

## This is the solution I came up with.

- i was able to call $("#element").foundation("toggle",$target,true) from the console and programmatically open and shut the accordion tab.

  - element is the accordion wrapper and target the specific tab, true is a param to indicate reflow needed
  - implementing that function into my app was more trouble than it was worth, for a number of reasons.
- i ended up just calling location.reload() and which essentially is like pressing the refresh button.  with a modal animation running at the same time it is barely noticeable
- so when all else fails manual over-ride could be a viable solution depending on what your individual page is

## There is a real answer

- in my research i came across quite a few similar github issues that had to do with Foundation plus some sort of dynamic rendering and/or third party framework/library.  every situation is a bit different so there isn't one answer
- if someone has specific knowledge of what why Foundation or React(possibly), wouldn't let me reInit,reflow,$(document).foundation or do any of the various supposed solutions: I would love to know.
- perhaps I could have done something different but if you look at my code I keep state to one component, I init my js plugins in componentDidMount - as far as i know this is what i am supposed to do. thanks